# how can change laravel filepath"?

Tags: laravel

I've a question, how can change filepath in laravel?

this is my code on under.

```
'public' => [

'driver' => 'local',

'root' => storage_path('app/public'),

'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',

'visibility' => 'public',
```

now, when I upload the file, it will saved to /storage/app/public/images

```
123.com/storage/app/public/images
```

how can change filepath to /public/storage/images

```
123.com/public/storage/images
```

Comment: your document root should be the public folder already ... you have a folder named 'public' in the 'public' folder?

Comment: because I have changed my default path, the default path is 123.com/public.
But I path change to 123.com, 

default is 
require __DIR__.’/../vendor/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/app.php’;
then I changed to 
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';